# Combine Array with same values, but add another array dictionary into the combined array

Tags: php, pdo

I have this PHP code to fetch the mysql data:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // create an array for the results 
        $menuItems['menu_items'][] = array(
            'item_id' => $row['item_id'],
            'rest_id' => $row['rest_id'],
            'item_name' => $row['item_name'],
            'item_genre' => $row['item_genre'],
            'item_price' => $row['item_price'],
            'item_descript' => $row['item_descript'],
            'wait_time' => $row['wait_time'],
            'ingredients' => array_filter(array(// do not display ingredients if null
                'ingredient_id' => $row['ingredient_id'],
                'ingredient_name' => $row['ingredient_name'],
                'ingredient_price' => $row['ingredient_price'],
                'ingredient_default' => $row['ingredient_default']
            ))
        );
        // print success or no error
        $menuItems['error'] .= '';
    }
    // check if any menu items exists
    if( $menuItems != null ) {
        echo json_encode($menuItems);
        print_r($menuItems);
    }             
    else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'There are currently no menu items for this location'));
    }
```

This is the JSON output array, but it's outputting the same menu item for each ingredient associated with it:

```
Array
(
[menu_items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 102
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Tilapia And Rice 
                [item_genre] => Fish %26 Seafood
                [item_price] => 9.50
                [item_descript] => Tilapia and rice 
                [wait_time] => 45
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                        [ingredient_id] => 1
                        [ingredient_name] => herbs
                        [ingredient_price] => 0.50
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 102
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Tilapia And Rice 
                [item_genre] => Fish %26 Seafood
                [item_price] => 9.50
                [item_descript] => Tilapia and rice 
                [wait_time] => 45
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                        [ingredient_id] => 2
                        [ingredient_name] => lemon
                        [ingredient_price] => 0.00
                        [ingredient_default] => 1
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 105
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Ninja Roll
                [item_genre] => Japanese
                [item_price] => 8.00
                [item_descript] => Sushi roll. 6-8 pieces. Captain's orders!
                [wait_time] => 30
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 106
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Sushi
                [item_genre] => Japanese
                [item_price] => 8.00
                [item_descript] => Menu item description (optional)
                [wait_time] => 30
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[error] => 
)
```

**I NEED the following though. Merge the ingredients into its associated menu item**

```
Array
(
[menu_items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 102
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Tilapia And Rice 
                [item_genre] => Fish %26 Seafood
                [item_price] => 9.50
                [item_descript] => Tilapia and rice 
                [wait_time] => 45
                [ingredients] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ingredient_id] => 1
                        [ingredient_name] => herbs
                        [ingredient_price] => 0.50
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ingredient_id] => 2
                        [ingredient_name] => lemon
                        [ingredient_price] => 0.00
                        [ingredient_default] => 1
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 105
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Ninja Roll
                [item_genre] => Japanese
                [item_price] => 8.00
                [item_descript] => Sushi roll. 6-8 pieces. Captain's orders!
                [wait_time] => 30
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 106
                [rest_id] => 67
                [item_name] => Sushi
                [item_genre] => Japanese
                [item_price] => 8.00
                [item_descript] => Menu item description (optional)
                [wait_time] => 30
                [ingredients] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[error] => 
)
```

How can I create the desired output array? I am so confused and am getting no where with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of associative arrays. When you control the index life becomes much easier.  This is especially true when dealing with one-to-many database results, as you are.

For example (and I'm obviously making assumptions/guesses about your model):

```
if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare($query)) {
    // initialise an array for the results 
    $menuItems = array();
    if ( $stmt->execute(array($rest_id)) ) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // Have we seen this menu before? If not, add it to the array
            if ( !isset($menuItems['menu_items'][$row['id']]) ) {
                $menuItems['menu_items'][$row['id']] = array(ingredients => array());
            }
            // Add the ingredient.
            $menuItems['menu_items'][$row['id']]['ingredients'][$row['ingred_id']] = $row['ingred_id'];
            $menuItems['error'] .= '';
        }
        if( $menuItems != null ) {
            echo json_encode($menuItems);
            //print_r($menuItems);
        }             
        else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'There are currently no menu items for this location'));
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above you create a list of menus where menu.id is the array key.  Each menu has a value 'ingredients', which likewise is an array.  In my example I use ingred_id as the key and value.  Obviously you'd modify the code to use ingred_id as the key plus an array of other ingredient info as the value.

Note that depending on the size of the database it might end up being more efficient to run multiple queries.  As it is now, you're pulling an awful lot of redundant data for each row.

Comment: I think you're right... I thought of that earlier. Might be easier to run two queries, one for populating menu items and one for populating the ingredients, and adding the ingredients array to the associated menu item.

Comment: After spending quite some time, not sure if this is what I was looking for but you caused me to try new things and I have updated my question with what I have going now with more of the ingredient labels if that helps provide you with more info necessary for solving this... seems better to just join the tables than running multiple queries... I have to have the item_id line up as that is the foriegn key for each ingredient

Comment: Any more ideas? I clarified my question a bit more

Comment: Ok, I finally spent two days playing with associative arrays and found out how to implement your answer. It works, but I feel it's not the best of practices what I am doing, so what's a better way to tackle this? Appreciate your help, it's finally working the way I want, but I am intrigue by your comment on efficiency.